# java producer consumer threads for monitoring audio

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronous

I'm making a DAW in Java, actually its more basic than that, I modelled it after an old Tascam 4-Track recorder I once owned. I'm trying to monitor audio while recording with as little latency (delay) between the two as possible. If I write the audio bytes in the same thread I'm reading them in there's a significant amount of latency (if you want to see the code I have I'll post it but it seemed irrelevant since I think it needs to be rewritten). What I had been thinking about doing is using a producer, consumer thread and a queue to store chunks of bytes in between. so my producer thread would read bytes from a `TargetDataLine` and store them in a queue, probably using a method that returns the number of bytes read so I can check for the EOF in my while loop. And create a concurrent thread that takes the chunks of bytes stored in the queue (when they are bytes to be written) and writes them to a `SourceDataLine`. My thought is two threads running simultaneously will be able to write the bytes almost at the same time they're read, or at least be better than what I have now but I want to know how other people have solved this problem.

Also I would need to make sure my consumer thread waits if there are no bytes in the queue and is notified when bytes are added to start writing bytes again, if some one would post an example of the proper way to synchronize the two threads I would appreciate it. I know they have to be in synchronized code blocks, should I use multiple locks? I'm not asking for an example specific to audio just a general example that adds something to a collection then removes it, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in "classic" java you can (and probbaly should) use a single lock object for producer-consumer implementations. something like

```
public final static Object LOCK = new Object();
```

then in your produce() method you'll have code like this:

```
synchronized(LOCK) {
   //place stuff in queue
   LOCK.notifyAll(); //wake up any sleepers
}
```

and in your consume() method you'll have the other side:

```
synchronized(LOCK) {
   if (anything in queue) {
      return something
   }
   //queue is empty - wait
   while (nothing in queue) { //while bit is important - we might wakeup for no reason or someone else might grab everything leaving us with nothing
      try {
         Lock.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
         //99% of java code ignores these spurious wakeups, and they also hardly ever really happen
      }
   }
}
```

but this is old-school. more modern versions of java have classes that neatly wrap all of this low level voodoo for you. for example [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). you could just define a "global" static queue and then use offer() and take() for you produce() and consume() implementations respectively.

but if youre really concerned with latency i'd go the extra mile and use a library written exactly for low-latency inter-thread ocmmunication. a good example of such a library is [the disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) that claims much better latencies than ArrayBlockingQueue.